# Can a Google Apps Script running as an editor add-on use the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-oauth, google-apps-script-addon

I'm creating a Google Docs add-on in Google Apps Script, and some of the functionality requires that I use the Google Drive advanced service as described in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced. After enabling the advanced service, my script is now requesting the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope, which is way overbroad for what I'm trying to do - I only want to touch the files that the user is actually using this add-on with, not their whole drive! I'd much rather be using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, which is restricted to files the user is actively using with the script.

I've tried setting the `@OnlyCurrentDoc` JSDoc tag as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/scopes#editor_add-on_scopes, but that only changes the broad `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly` - it doesn't change the Drive API scope.

Also, I've verified that the script *does* actually need the `auth/drive` scope, because when I went into the project manifest and explicitly requested `auth/drive.file`, I got a 404 response with **API call to drive.revisions.list failed with error: File not found: 1Sj_oq93ny5q9348ncyo8934nyc at getAuthors(Code:54) at showSidebar(Code:20)**. That's exactly what I'd expect for a file that hasn't been "tagged" for use with this script.

Here's a very minimal gdocs addon that shows the issue:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem("Get revisions", "getRevisions");
  menu.addToUi();
}


function getRevisions() {
  var docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  Logger.log("Document id: "+docId);
  var revs = Drive.Revisions.list(docId);
  Logger.log("Found revisions: "+revs.items.length);
}
```

Again, this works just fine with the default `auth/drive` scope, but not with `auth/drive.file`.

The documentation for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` specifies that it grants "Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app." according to the docs at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing. What isn't clear is: how does Google determine what files have been "created or opened by the app", especially when it comes to editor addons? I would think that any document that has had the add-on enabled would count as "opened by the app", but I guess not. Is there any way to make this scope work?

Comment: This problem is not exclusive to the advanced drive service.  The built-in `DriveApp` service will throw the error: "You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById" when using the code: `var docId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getId();var file = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);`  I ran some test code using `FormApp` instead of `DocumentApp`.  Technically, this may not be a bug, but the active doc should be included in files that "auth/drive.file" can access.  I've created an issue on the issue tracker: ["auth/drive.file" does not give access](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135299052)

Comment: That's great, thanks, I've added my voice. Glad I'm not the only one!